# Problems with @Column() annotation when I use the unique = true constraint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I'm making a basic user registration in Spring Boot and I use the `@Column(unique = true)` annotation but it isn't working. I can register multiple user with the same email.

Here is my code:

```java
package io.agile.ppmtool.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Email(message = "Username needs to be an email")
    @NotBlank(message = "username is required")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter your full name")
    private String fullName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password field is required")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;
    private Date created_At;
    private Date updated_At;
}
```

I hope somebody can help me why this annotation don't work for me.

Comment: do you have liquibase if have it you must change liquibase file too

Comment: No, I don't have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unique` in `@Column` is used only if you let your JPA provider create the database for you - it will create the unique constraint on the specified column.

But if you already have the database, or you alter it once created, then `unique` doesn't have any effect.

So you need the unique constraint in the database somehow, having only the `@Column` is no guarantee.